# Execute function on onloadend event

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to execute functions after an `onloadend` event in order to append the uploaded image to a canvas and do some post procesing.

```
let fileInput = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    if(ev.target.files) {
        let file = ev.target.files[0];
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = e.target.result;
            image.onload = function(ev) {
                function one(){
                    // some code here...
                }

                function two(){
                    // some code here...
                }

                // etc..
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works. You are successfully running the code in the onloadend event, but your code merely declares two functions. It doesn't run them. I have included some `console.log`s to illustrate my point.

```js
let fileInput = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    
    console.log('change event fired');  
  
    if(ev.target.files) {
        let file = ev.target.files[0];
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        
            console.log('loadEnd event fired');
        
            var image = new Image();

            function one() {
              console.log('image.load event fired');
              const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
              const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
              context.drawImage(image,0,0);
            };

            image.onload = one;
            image.src = e.target.result;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input type=file id=fileinput />
</form>

<canvas id=canvas width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Ok I see, but how can I call for multiple functions ? I have a total of 16 functions because I'm implementing a code that I want to run only when the image is uploaded.

Comment: Here is the code in question : https://openprocessing.org/sketch/991831